# Read string in string

Tags: c#, string

If you have this:

```
foreach(string n in txtList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Output:

```
[HKEY_Something_Something\.abc]
[HKEY_Something_Something\.defg]
[HKEY_Something_Something\.ijklmn]
```

How do I get what's between the "." and the "]"   ?

Comment: this depends.. Is there always only one dot? one backslash?

Comment: Read about Regular Expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it always follow that format, changing your code to this should output what you want:

```
foreach(string n in txtList)
{
  int startindex = n.IndexOf(@"\.") + 2;
  Console.WriteLine(n.Substring( startindex, n.Length-startindex-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 foreach(string n in txtList)
    {
        string str[] = n.Split('.');
        if (str.Length > 0)
        {
            string s = str[str.Length-1];
            Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.Length-1));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var s = @"[HKEY_Something_Something\.abc]";
var result = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=\.)[^]]*(?=]$)")
// result == "abc"
```

Short explanation of the regex:

```
(?<=\.) - preceded by a dot
[^]]*   - anything which isn't a ']'
(?=]$)  - followed by a ']' and the end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var per = n.IndexOf("."); // may need to add +1 to get past . index.
var len = n.IndexOf("]") - per - 1;

var val = n.Substring(per, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
int dotPosition = n.LastIndexOf(".") + 1; // +1 because we start AFTER the dot.
int bracketPosition = n.LastIndexOf("]"); // can do "n.Length - 2" too.
Console.WriteLine(n.Substring(dotPosition, bracketPosition - dotPosition));
```

More complicated answer: use Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

For example with RegEx:

```
  Match match = Regex.Match(n, @"\.(.*)\]");  
  string result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```